# UIRefreshControl not refreshing xml data

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Im new here and am stumped trying to add a pull to refresh control to update my xml table view. I'm getting the proper pull to refresh animation, but the data is not refreshing. Please help.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.PLACEHOLDER.rss.xml"];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull 
        to refresh..."];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;

}

- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)sender {
    // ...refresh code
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.PLACEHOLDER.rss.xml"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    (void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [sender endRefreshing];
}
```

Comment: You didn't include the relevant delegate methods for when the download completes or the XML has finished parsing.

Comment: Do you call [self.tableView reloadData] in the delegate method when your request is finished?

Comment: Im new to this. Can you provide more detail on how this would be done. Thank you both for the updates.